# Most efficient mutable collection to use to remove first or last element

Tags: scala, collections, mutable

I need to repeatedly remove the first item from a collection in scala. What is the most efficient collection to use for this case.

What about removing the last element? Should I use the same or a different type of collection?

My initial research pointed [no pun intended] to [DoubleLinkedList](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/mutable/DoubleLinkedList.html), but this has been deprecated.

I've tried this on a ListBuffer. It works but I don't know if it is most efficient

```
  c -= c.head
  d -= d.last
```

Comment: What have you already tried (code)? Have you read [doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you are trying to do. If you are repeatedly removing the first and last item and doing something with them perhaps use an array and keep track of your first/last indices?

Comment: @cchantep while that page is often enough, the full docs for the collections library are at least 50 pages IIRC and there are useful considerations (indeed, other collections!) in those pages

Answer (score 1):

You may verify if selected data structure in line with your expectations on this [page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).